# How to set code page in pos receipt printers

Tags: android, printing, usb

I am trying to create pos receipt printer. On printing English, it is working fine. When I tried to print with another code page 8 (Hebrew) the
printer prints with unknown characters.

```
    void printData(){
                 bulkTransfer(new byte[]{27,116,8});
                 bulkTransfer("דְמוּי אָדָם".getBytes()); //דְמוּי אָדָם Android 
    }



private void bulkTransfer(byte[] data) {
                    if (data != null)
                        mUsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(mUsbEndPoint, data, data.length, TIME_OUT);
                }
```

Comment: This is highly dependent on the printer. You need to find the ESC/POS manual from the printer's manufacturer to find the right code to select the Hebrew codepage. Certain printers must also be configured through a PC application to have other codepages installed.

Comment: @cory.todd, thanks for replying me.